# If controler logic

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where I need to validate cases that gets matches with the output JSON: I wrote code inside if controller:(so if all the cases matches, we will say pass and print the value) And its actually working fine..

```
("${C_etrTimestamp}"=="${ETRTIMESTAMP}")&&("${C_EventName}"=="${EVENTNAME}")&&("${C_EventType}"=="${EVENTTYPE}")&&("${C_AreaName}"=="${AREANAME}")&&("${C_AreaType}"=="${AREATYPE}")&&("${C_additionalInfo}"=="${ADDITIONALINFO}")&&("${C_resultStatusCode}"=="${RESULTSTATUSCODE}")&&("${C_resultStatusMessage}"=="${RESULTSTATUSMESSAGE}")
```

But I also need to print the results those doesn't matches: so I created another `if controller`. and inside that I wrote the below code:(but its not working for me) so the 1st `if` is getting executed. but the results those are not matching are not getting entered into the 2nd `if controller`.

```
("${C_etrTimestamp}"!=="${ETRTIMESTAMP}")or("${C_EventName}"!=="${EVENTNAME}")or("${C_EventType}"!=="${EVENTTYPE}")or("${C_AreaName}"!=="${AREANAME}")or("${C_AreaType}"!=="${AREATYPE}")or("${C_additionalInfo}"!=="${ADDITIONALINFO}")or("${C_resultStatusCode}"!=="${RESULTSTATUSCODE}")or("${C_resultStatusMessage}"!=="${RESULTSTATUSMESSAGE}")
```

can anyone suggest me what to do?

Comment: I modified the 2nd if controller but still its not getting entered for mismatch cases: Please help

  ("${C_etrTimestamp}"!="${ETRTIMESTAMP}")||("${C_EventName}"!="${EVENTNAME}")||("${C_EventType}"!="${EVENTTYPE}")||("${C_AreaName}"!="${AREANAME}")||("${C_AreaType}"!="${AREATYPE}")||("${C_additionalInfo}"!="${ADDITIONALINFO}")||("${C_resultStatusCode}"!="${RESULTSTATUSCODE}")||("${C_resultStatusMessage}"!="${RESULTSTATUSMESSAGE}")

Comment: the issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to negate every clause, make a second condition an exact opposite of the first with `!(...):

```
!(("${C_etrTimestamp}"=="${ETRTIMESTAMP}")&&("${C_EventName}"=="${EVENTNAME}")&&("${C_EventType}"=="${EVENTTYPE}")&&("${C_AreaName}"=="${AREANAME}")&&("${C_AreaType}"=="${AREATYPE}")&&("${C_additionalInfo}"=="${ADDITIONALINFO}")&&("${C_resultStatusCode}"=="${RESULTSTATUSCODE}")&&("${C_resultStatusMessage}"=="${RESULTSTATUSMESSAGE}"))
```

You could also simplify conditions to one comparison with all variables inside it (since you want all of them to match), make is a bit shorter and easier to read.

First If:

```
"${C_etrTimestamp}${C_EventName}${C_EventType}..."=="${ETRTIMESTAMP}${EVENTNAME}${EVENTTYPE}..."
```

Second If:

```
!("${C_etrTimestamp}${C_EventName}${C_EventType}..."=="${ETRTIMESTAMP}${EVENTNAME}${EVENTTYPE}...")
```